# WinDbg: How do I get the message displayed in a Word dialog from a core dump?

Tags: ms-word, office-interop, windbg

I'm doing some Office automation with MS Word from a C# application, and I'm finding that Word sometimes hangs. I can't reproduce the hang in a developer environment, so I'm hoping I can diagnose exactly why Word is hanging by taking a core dump and then analyzing it using WinDbg.

If I run kb, I get this stack trace (I've left off everything after the warning as it's probably irrelevant):

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
003bc94c 762ed846 00037b72 00000008 00000000 user32!NtUserWaitMessage+0x15
003bc988 762eda5c 00047b12 00037b72 00000008 user32!DialogBox2+0x222
003bc9b4 762ed98a 59870000 0089aa30 00037b72 user32!InternalDialogBox+0xe5
003bc9d4 762ed70e 59870000 0089aa30 00037b72 user32!DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW+0x37
003bc9f4 59acdf5e 59870000 0089aa30 00037b72 user32!DialogBoxIndirectParamW+0x1b
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
```

So this seems to indicate that Word is hanging because it's showing a dialog box. **How can I get the contents of that dialog box?**

If I look at the memory at address 0089aa30, I see this:

```
........................3....
.M.i.c.r.o.s.o.f.t. .W.o.r.d.
........T.a.h.o.m.a..........
....P#.!.*...........O.K.....
...........PW.!.*...........&
.H.e.l.p..................P..
.............................
....P+...r.......M.S.O.U.N.I.
S.T.A.T...W.o.r.d. .c.a.n.n.o
.t. .o.p.e.n. .t.h.e. .e.x.i.
s.t.i.n.g. .f.i.l.e..... .(.N
.o.r.m.a.l.)................@
..+.........M.S.O.U.N.I.S.T.A
.T...2.0.0.5.2.1.............
```

So to me this says that the message in the dialog is "Word cannot open the existing file (Normal)".

Am I on the right track? Am I looking at the right bit of memory?

Is there any way to get the exact memory address of the message? (I feel like I'm guessing a bit, because the above message just happens to be close by in memory to a parameter to DialogBoxIndirectParam.) I have looked at the MSDN docs for [DialogBoxIndirectParam](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645461(v=vs.85).aspx), hoping to figure out exactly where in memory I should expect to see the dialog's message, but didn't get very far.

---

**Edit**: After seeing blabb's (absolutely incredible) answer, I have attempted to perform the same steps in WinDbg for my MS Word core dump. Here's the output:

```
0:000> ub 762ed98a 
user32!DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW+0x1f:
762ed972 83c801          or      eax,1
762ed975 50              push    eax
762ed976 ff7518          push    dword ptr [ebp+18h]
762ed979 ff7514          push    dword ptr [ebp+14h]
762ed97c ff7510          push    dword ptr [ebp+10h]
762ed97f ff750c          push    dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
762ed982 ff7508          push    dword ptr [ebp+8]
762ed985 e809000000      call    user32!InternalDialogBox (762ed993)
0:000> .frame /r 2
02 003bc9b4 762ed98a user32!InternalDialogBox+0xe5
eax=00000000 ebx=00037b72 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=003bc97c edi=003bc918
eip=762eda5c esp=003bc990 ebp=003bc9b4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
user32!InternalDialogBox+0xe5:
762eda5c 5f              pop     edi
0:000> dc /c 1 003bc990 l8
003bc990  00047b12  .{..
003bc994  00037b72  r{..
003bc998  00000008  ....
003bc99c  00000000  ....
003bc9a0  00000000  ....
003bc9a4  00037b72  r{..
003bc9a8  003bcb98  ..;.
003bc9ac  00000000  ....
```

I know I'm looking at the wrong bit of memory (i.e. the address I'm passing to dc is incorrect), but I don't know why. I used ".frame /r 2" to fetch the address of esp, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You can make your life easier by downloading and using [pde](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DAE128BD454CF957!7152&authkey=!AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w&ithint=folder%2czip) from Andrew Richards. In Windbg, load it as `.load <yourpathtopde>\pde.dll` and execute `!dpx`. It will show you amongst other things all strings that can be retrieved from the stack.

Comment: As you are most likely looking in the right direction already regarding the error, easier still might be to download `procmon` from sysinternals. Start it, run your code, stop it and go to `tools - count occurences - column: result - count ` and filter on errors or access denied values.

Comment: Thanks Lieven. Given the bug is intermittent I think procmon might be challenging. Wasn't aware of pde so I'll give that a try now.

Comment: I've run !dpx using PDE and can't see any other strings in memory that could be displayed in a Word dialog. So thanks for that, that seems to confirm that I'm looking in the right place. I still kind of wish there was a way to go straight to the dialog's message from the stack trace, though, rather than having to look through every string in memory. It feels like this should be possible if I understood how DialogBoxIndirectParam works better...

Comment: No doubt there is but I don't know how. Looking at MSDN I can't find a way to get to the dialog box content starting from the parameters passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks anyway Lieven, the pde tip was really useful. :)

Comment: use **!pde.dpx -du** and **!pde.dpx -da** to dump unicode and ansi strings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The InternalDialogBox Api Takes Six Arguments

```
C:\>cdb -c ".fnent user32!InternalDialogbox;q" cdb | grep Params
Params:    0n6 (0x18 bytes)
```

you can try deciphering this call by doing a backward disassembly on the return address on stack

```
0:000> kb 1
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0017fad8 778be0d5 77860000 001ec4f0 00000000 USER32!InternalDialogBox

0:000> ub @$ra
USER32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x66d:
778be0b8 e87c48fdff      call    USER32!MessageBeep (77892939)
778be0bd 56              push    esi
778be0be 53              push    ebx
778be0bf 6848d68b77      push    offset USER32!MB_DlgProc (778bd648)
778be0c4 ff75ac          push    dword ptr [ebp-54h]
778be0c7 ff75e4          push    dword ptr [ebp-1Ch]
778be0ca ff35d0908c77    push    dword ptr [USER32!hmodUser (778c90d0)]
778be0d0 e8a059fdff      call    USER32!InternalDialogBox (77893a75)
```

in a crash dump you can substitute address instead of register or you can 
do .frame /r {frame number} to fetch the address of esp

```
0:000> dc /c 1 @esp l8
0017fadc  778be0d5  ...w
0017fae0  77860000  ...w
0017fae4  001ec4f0  ....
0017fae8  00000000  ....
0017faec  778bd648  H..w
0017faf0  0017fcd8  ....
0017faf4  00000000  ....
0017faf8  00000001  ....
```

1) The first argument is hModUser a global variable
2) The fourth argument is a DialogProc callback that is documented 
3) 3rd and 6th argument are NULL

the second argument consits of an array of  [DLGTEMPLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645394(v=vs.85).aspx) followed by [DLGITEMTEMPLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644997(v=vs.85).aspx) structure read the document for the format of this variable sized array

the fifth argument is MSGBOXPARAMS structure

a sample dump and deciphering the dump for the variable sized array as follows

```
0:000> db 1ec4f0 l f8 
001ec4f0  c5 01 c8 80 00 00 00 00-02 00 1a 01 9b 00 a7 00  ................
001ec500  3e 00 00 00 00 00 54 00-68 00 69 00 73 00 20 00  >.....T.h.i.s. .
001ec510  69 00 73 00 20 00 4d 00-79 00 20 00 43 00 61 00  i.s. .M.y. .C.a.
001ec520  70 00 74 00 69 00 6f 00-6e 00 20 00 46 00 6f 00  p.t.i.o.n. .F.o.
001ec530  72 00 20 00 32 00 30 00-31 00 35 00 20 00 43 00  r. .2.0.1.5. .C.
001ec540  6f 00 6d 00 6d 00 75 00-6e 00 69 00 74 00 79 00  o.m.m.u.n.i.t.y.
001ec550  20 00 76 00 73 00 00 00-ff 7f 00 00 01 00 03 50   .v.s..........P
001ec560  00 00 00 00 71 00 2a 00-32 00 0e 00 01 00 ff ff  ....q.*.2.......
001ec570  80 00 4f 00 4b 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 80 20 02 50  ..O.K........ .P
001ec580  00 00 00 00 07 00 0e 00-8c 00 09 00 ff ff ff ff  ................
001ec590  82 00 54 00 68 00 69 00-73 00 20 00 69 00 73 00  ..T.h.i.s. .i.s.
001ec5a0  20 00 6d 00 79 00 20 00-66 00 69 00 72 00 73 00   .m.y. .f.i.r.s.
001ec5b0  74 00 20 00 54 00 65 00-73 00 74 00 20 00 77 00  t. .T.e.s.t. .w.
001ec5c0  69 00 74 00 68 00 20 00-32 00 30 00 31 00 35 00  i.t.h. .2.0.1.5.
001ec5d0  20 00 63 00 6f 00 6d 00-6d 00 75 00 6e 00 69 00   .c.o.m.m.u.n.i.
001ec5e0  74 00 79 00 00 00 00 00                          t.y.....
0:000> dt ConsoleApplication1!DLGTEMPLATE 1ec4f0
   +0x000 style            : 0x80c801c5
   +0x004 dwExtendedStyle  : 0
   +0x008 cdit             : 2
   +0x00a x                : 0x11a
   +0x00c y                : 0x9b
   +0x00e cx               : 0xa7
   +0x010 cy               : 0x3e
0:000> du 1ec504
001ec504  ""
0:000> du 1ec506
001ec506  "This is My Caption For 2015 Comm"
001ec546  "unity vs"
0:000> dt ConsoleApplication1!DLGITEMTEMPLATE 1ec55c
   +0x000 style            : 0x50030001
   +0x004 dwExtendedStyle  : 0
   +0x008 x                : 0x71
   +0x00a y                : 0x2a
   +0x00c cx               : 0x32
   +0x00e cy               : 0xe
   +0x010 id               : 1
0:000> $$ 80 is a predfined button and the text is OK
0:000> dt ConsoleApplication1!DLGITEMTEMPLATE 1ec57c
   +0x000 style            : 0x50022080
   +0x004 dwExtendedStyle  : 0
   +0x008 x                : 7
   +0x00a y                : 0xe
   +0x00c cx               : 0x8c
   +0x00e cy               : 9
   +0x010 id               : 0xffff
0:000> $$ 82 is a predfined static text and the text is 
0:000> du 1ec592
001ec592  "This is my first Test with 2015 "
001ec5d2  "community"
```

here is a MSGBOXPARAMSW dump

```
0:000> dt ConsoleApplication1!MSGBOXPARAMSW 0017fcd8 
   +0x000 cbSize           : 0x28
   +0x004 hwndOwner        : (null) 
   +0x008 hInstance        : (null) 
   +0x00c lpszText         : 0x01172150  "This is my first Test with 2015 community"
   +0x010 lpszCaption      : 0x011720f8  "This is My Caption For 2015 Community vs"
   +0x014 dwStyle          : 0
   +0x018 lpszIcon         : (null) 
   +0x01c dwContextHelpId  : 0
   +0x020 lpfnMsgBoxCallback : (null) 
   +0x024 dwLanguageId     : 0
```

**EDIT**

**created a dump from taskmanager and loaded it**

```
0:000> .shell -ci "version" grep DMP
Full memory user mini dump: C:\Users\HP\Desktop\cons.DMP
command line: 'windbg  -z cons.DMP'  Debugger Process 0x17CC 
.shell: Process exited
```

**just to be sure resetting the context record**

```
0:000> .cxr
Resetting default scope
```

**dumping stacktrace 9the frame of interest is not at top here)**

```
0:000> kb 5
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0028f6fc 778766c9 7789382a 00000000 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
01 0028f700 7789382a 00000000 00000000 00000000 user32!NtUserWaitMessage+0xc
02 0028f734 77893b27 00aa0350 00000000 00000000 user32!DialogBox2+0x207
03 0028f758 778be0d5 77860000 002f63f0 00000000 user32!InternalDialogBox+0xcb
04 0028f7fc 778be659 00000000 69d52104 69d52108 user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x68a
```

**overriding local context for frame number of interest**

```
0:000> .frame /c /r 04
04 0028f7fc 778be659 user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x68a
eax=00000001 ebx=0028f958 ecx=0028f458 edx=77ad70f4 esi=005fab18 edi=00000001
eip=778be0d5 esp=0028f760 ebp=0028f7fc iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x68a:
778be0d5 8945e8          mov     dword ptr [ebp-18h],eax ss:0023:0028f7e4=00000000

checking esp you can use esp as it is instead of groping for address

0:000> dc /c 1 @esp l 8
0028f760  77860000  ...w
0028f764  002f63f0  .c/.
0028f768  00000000  ....
0028f76c  778bd648  H..w
0028f770  0028f958  X.(.
0028f774  00000000  ....
0028f778  00000001  ....
0028f77c  0028f958  X.(.
```

**dumping DLGTEMPLATE second arg**

```
0:000> db 2f63f0 lf8
002f63f0  c5 01 c8 80 00 00 00 00-02 00 1a 01 9b 00 a7 00  ................
002f6400  3e 00 00 00 00 00 54 00-68 00 69 00 73 00 20 00  >.....T.h.i.s. .
002f6410  69 00 73 00 20 00 4d 00-79 00 20 00 43 00 61 00  i.s. .M.y. .C.a.
002f6420  70 00 74 00 69 00 6f 00-6e 00 20 00 46 00 6f 00  p.t.i.o.n. .F.o.
002f6430  72 00 20 00 32 00 30 00-31 00 35 00 20 00 43 00  r. .2.0.1.5. .C.
002f6440  6f 00 6d 00 6d 00 75 00-6e 00 69 00 74 00 79 00  o.m.m.u.n.i.t.y.
002f6450  20 00 76 00 73 00 00 00-ff 7f 00 00 01 00 03 50   .v.s..........P
002f6460  00 00 00 00 71 00 2a 00-32 00 0e 00 01 00 ff ff  ....q.*.2.......
002f6470  80 00 4f 00 4b 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 80 20 02 50  ..O.K........ .P
002f6480  00 00 00 00 07 00 0e 00-8c 00 09 00 ff ff ff ff  ................
002f6490  82 00 54 00 68 00 69 00-73 00 20 00 69 00 73 00  ..T.h.i.s. .i.s.
002f64a0  20 00 6d 00 79 00 20 00-66 00 69 00 72 00 73 00   .m.y. .f.i.r.s.
002f64b0  74 00 20 00 54 00 65 00-73 00 74 00 20 00 77 00  t. .T.e.s.t. .w.
002f64c0  69 00 74 00 68 00 20 00-32 00 30 00 31 00 35 00  i.t.h. .2.0.1.5.
002f64d0  20 00 63 00 6f 00 6d 00-6d 00 75 00 6e 00 69 00   .c.o.m.m.u.n.i.
002f64e0  74 00 79 00 00 00 00 00                          t.y.....
```

typeinfo (you need proper private pdb or hack load a binary which you compiled into address space or add the DLGTEMPLATE struct into the official pdb for user32 from ms ( i thought i had a post explaining this in se but i cant seem to find) ill link it later if i find it or sitesearch google for how to add typeinfo to pdb in site:woodmann.com

```
0:000> dt cons!DLGTEMPLATE poi(@esp+4)
   +0x000 style            : 0x80c801c5
   +0x004 dwExtendedStyle  : 0
   +0x008 cdit             : 2
   +0x00a x                : 0n282
   +0x00c y                : 0n155
   +0x00e cx               : 0n167
   +0x010 cy               : 0n62

0:000> du poi(@esp+4)+16
002f6406  "This is My Caption For 2015 Comm"
002f6446  "unity vs"
```

**edit 2  this is for a live session in dump mode you need to modify a pdb as you cant use execution commands**

**we are in a live dbg session we can use step commands which arent available in dmp mode**

```
0:000> .tlist -c -v 
 0n3324 Msgbox.exe
       Session: 1  User: HP-PC\HP  Command Line: Msgbox.exe
```

**lets search for some typeinfo we need**

```
0:000> dt *!*DLGTEMPLATE*
0:000> $$ no the thype info is not available
0:000> $$ we know ole32.dll has it 
0:000> $$ so lets hack load it
```

**allocate some memory**

```
0:000> .dvalloc 1000
Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 00020000
save the current eip

0:000> ? @eip
Evaluate expression: 2008221094 = 77b305a6
```

**embed the modulename string at some address in the allocated memory**

```
0:000> ea 20100 "ole32.dll"
0:000> db 20100 l20
00020100  6f 6c 65 33 32 2e 64 6c-6c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ole32.dll.......
00020110  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

**Assemble a LoadLibraryA call inline**

```
0:000> a 20000
00020000 push 20100
push 20100
00020005 call kernel32!LoadLibraryA
call kernel32!LoadLibraryA
0002000a
```

**change eip to the detour address**

```
0:000> r eip = 20000

single step to load a dll into the address space 


0:000> p
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=0026f80c edx=77ad70f4 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=00020005 esp=0026f824 ebp=0026f854 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
00020005 e852395877      call    kernel32!LoadLibraryA (775a395c)
0:000> p
ModLoad: 77930000 77a8c000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 75ee0000 75f81000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 77530000 7754f000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 76030000 760fc000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
eax=77930000 ebx=00000000 ecx=77ae6570 edx=002b0174 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=0002000a esp=0026f828 ebp=0026f854 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
0002000a 0000            add     byte ptr [eax],al          ds:0023:77930000=4d
```

**reset eip back**

```
0:000> r eip = 77b305a6
```

**we research the typeinfo and bingo we have it**

```
0:000> dt *!*DLGTEMPLATE*
          ole32!LPDLGTEMPLATEA
          ole32!LPDLGTEMPLATE
          ole32!LPDLGTEMPLATEW
          ole32!LPCDLGTEMPLATE
          ole32!LPCDLGTEMPLATEA
          ole32!LPCDLGTEMPLATEW
          ole32!DLGTEMPLATE
          ole32!DLGTEMPLATE
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for all of your efforts in this, I was absolutely blown away when I first read this. I attempted to complete the same steps as you and have edited the question to include my WinDbg output. For me, InternalDialogBox isn't at the top of the call stack, so I attempted to get the correct esp address using .frame /r, as you suggested. But unfortunately the output of dc is not giving me the arguments to InternalDialogBox. Any chance you're able to tell what I'm doing wrong from my edit?

Comment: it depends i added some info by creating a dump of a running process in task manager and annotating it see if that helps (i cant seem to corelate your earlier dump address with the latest edit  (aslr doesnt apply to dump iirc but the address vary in your posts is that the same dump or a differnent dump )

Comment: Sorry, I switched dumps. :) I'll see if I can find the original and update the question.

Comment: edit btw you can skip all this crap and simply use the second argument from kb :) as well since windbg gives the correct 3 args for a call in kb  and when pasting from windbg window do not edit the address etc i could have given you ox12345678 to test if your first post had the address in it intact  it is probably 0089aa30 from your first post in the first dump

Comment: I've updated the question so at least I'm consistently using the same dump now! Yeah I see what you mean by just using the arguments from kb, it's the bit about needing a private pdb or hack loading a binary which worries me. I'll read through your edit carefully now and will hopefully have some progress, thanks again.

Comment: I see in your edit you switch to one frame below InternalDialogBox (SoftModalMessageBox in your example). So Ithat was my mistake, I should have used /frame /c /r 3, and that does get the arguments correctly (and matches the results of kb). Getting the typoinfo part doesn't work for me, but I will google for that myself. :) Thank you very much again, I'm amazed that this kind of thing is even possible.

Comment: well i have added a live debug scene on adding typeinfo  and here is the link to add typeinfo to an official pdb  http://www.woodmann.com/forum/entry.php?227-How-To-Add-TypeInfo-So-That-Dt-Commands-Work-Properly-In-Windbg